# ACL installation error - "Exception: Plugin Acl could not be found"

Tags: cakephp, migration, acl, cakephp-3.7

I m trying to use ACL in Cake 3.7. I followed all steps but i wrote this script:

```
bin/cake Migrations.migrations migrate -p Acl
```

give this error:

> Exception: Plugin Acl could not be found. in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aclTutorial/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/PluginCollection.php, line 127]

Comment: It would be better if you copied/pasted the error log rather than attaching a snapshot of it

Comment: The plugin doesn't seem to be installed (correctly). Please clarify if you're using this plugin: **https://github.com/cakephp/acl**, and if so, what steps you took to install it.

Comment: in Composer.json:   "require": {
  "php": ">=5.3.0",
  "cakephp/cakephp": "3.7.1",
  "cakephp/acl": "^0.4.0",
  "cakephp/debug_kit": "^3.17"
 },

Comment: And vendors i have files with Acl.  I followed each step

Comment: in this part give me error: "Creating tables
To create the ACL requires tables, run the following Migrations command:

bin/cake migrations migrate -p Acl"

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed the ACL plugin via composer and loaded the ACL plugin in config/bootstrap.php?

Plugin::load('Acl', ['bootstrap' => true]);

Comment: yeah, first run this command in console "composer require cakephp/acl" then this "$this->addPlugin('Acl');" in src/Application.php:

Answer (score 0):

I can fix it. Cake 3.7 add two bin, vendor and vendors. Acl installed in vendors but no in the other. I copy and set direcction to vendor. it fix.